Accessing point cloud data via python API
My object is originally a spherical MESH, and it is transformed into a point cloud using several geometry nodes (mesh to points, raycast, etc).
Then I would like to access the data associated to this point cloud : I can see those data in the datasheet of the UI like shown on the image, and the UI shows a perfectly fine cloud, but impossible for me to acccess the data via python API.
I have tried using depsgraph_get and evaluated_get but the result is always of MESH type, and no vertices in it (object_evaluated.data.vertices), it is like nothing has been evaluated.
One side note is that, adding a PointToVertices node at the end, I can access the vertices location, but the object is not Point Cloud anymore, and it is difficult to color a purely vertex object...


If someone has an idea how to get those point cloud data (in particular location) that would be great.
Edit :
An interesting thing is that on a very simple example : a cube with 1/ node scale by two 2/ mesh to point. Then I read attribute position obj.data.attributes['position'] -> the points are (-1,1),(1,1), etc. instead of (2,2),(-2,2) like it is on datasheet => blender bug I suppose


You should be able to access the mesh attributes with obj.data.attributes["attr_name"]. Does that not work?

"One side note is that, adding a PointToVertices node at the end, I can access the vertices location, but the object is not Point Cloud anymore, and it is difficult to color a purely vertex object..." - so convert it back to points after you set the color

@Jakemoyo thanks for the answer, I have tried using attributes, with a Store Named Attribute but the vector returned obj.data.attributes['position_pts'].data are all (0,0,0).. I have put Input Position node as Value,

It does look like you're trying to store a different amount of point data than you have vertices in the mesh. You might have to use a "Sample Nearest X" type node to convert the point position data into a per-vert value. I'm not totally sure but I think that might also be part of your problem.

@Jakemoyo There is a big difference between the original and evaluated geometry: original is a small sphere, and the evaluated is projected sphere on the scene like disco ball would do. I don't think I could use Nearest node. It seems like a blender bug that doesn't want to evaluate for POINT type, (but OK for MESH); obj.data.attributes['position'].data is giving the location of the original mesh instead of the output geometry (position_pts was giving zero but maybe my custom attribute was wrong..)

An interesting thing is that on a very simple example : a cube with 1/ node scale by two 2/ mesh to point. Then I read attribute position -> has not been scale, only coordinate of original geometry => blender bug or misunderstanding of what obj.data.attributes['position'] is suppose to be ?

I do not think it is a bug. The depsgraph documentation says "(...) is needed every time one needs to access state with (...) modifiers taken into account.". But trying to apply a GN modifier generating a Point Cloud fails because it is not generating a mesh. I think Point Cloud is something "on the fly" that can be use only by another modifier or shader. What is returned by obj.data.attributes['position'] is the "Cube" Mesh vertices coordinates, not the Point Cloud points coordinates.

@StefLAncien not really a bug indeeed, but I would say a limitation of Blender, or potential improvement to be done. Because currently I see no direct way to get these data in python whereas I see it in the UI datasheet which is a bit crazy to me

Please also note that the depsgraph is working with the GN MeshToPoint, because adding a PointToMesh after I can access the data properly.

Indeed, but the PointToMesh node is generating a Mesh, so the GN modifier can be apply in this case.

I'm not sure I understand what you want. As I wrote in a comment, you can:

convert points to vertices
modify as you want
convert back to points

which on a high level is expressed as such:
ob = C.object
points_to_verts(target=ob)
    
# modify the points to your liking
for v in ob.data.vertices:
    v.co *= 2

verts_to_points(target=ob, radius=0.05)

 The whole code then becomes:
from bpy import context as C, data as D


def main():
    ob = C.object
    points_to_verts(target=ob)
    
    # modify the points to your liking
    for v in ob.data.vertices:
        v.co *= 2
        
    verts_to_points(target=ob, radius=0.05)


def points_to_verts(*, target):
    temp_name = "Temporary datablock - delete it"
    
    ob = target
    mod = ob.modifiers.new(name=temp_name, type='NODES')

    tree = D.node_groups.new(name=temp_name, type='GeometryNodeTree')    
    tree.interface.new_socket(
        name='Geometry', in_out='OUTPUT', socket_type='NodeSocketGeometry')
    tree.interface.new_socket(
        name='Geometry', in_out='INPUT', socket_type='NodeSocketGeometry')        

    node_in = tree.nodes.new(type='NodeGroupInput')
    node_points_to_verts = tree.nodes.new(type='GeometryNodePointsToVertices')
    node_out = tree.nodes.new(type='NodeGroupOutput')

    tree.links.new(
        output = node_in.outputs['Geometry'],
        input  = node_points_to_verts.inputs['Points']
    )
    tree.links.new(
        output = node_points_to_verts.outputs['Mesh'],
        input  = node_out.inputs['Geometry']
    )
    
    mod.node_group = tree
    dg = C.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
    oldme = ob.data
    newme = ob.evaluated_get(dg).data.copy()
    ob.modifiers.clear()
    ob.data = newme
    newme.name = oldme.name
    D.meshes.remove(oldme)
    D.node_groups.remove(tree)


def verts_to_points(*, target, radius):
    tree_name = 'Verts to Points'
    ob = target
    mod = ob.modifiers.new(name='geonodes', type='NODES')
    
    tree = D.node_groups.get(tree_name)
    
    if not tree:
        tree = D.node_groups.new(name=tree_name, type='GeometryNodeTree')
        
        tree.interface.new_socket(
            name='Geometry', in_out='OUTPUT', socket_type='NodeSocketGeometry')
        tree.interface.new_socket(
            name='Geometry', in_out='INPUT', socket_type='NodeSocketGeometry')        

        node_in = tree.nodes.new(type='NodeGroupInput')
        node_mesh_to_points = tree.nodes.new(type='GeometryNodeMeshToPoints')
        # you may want to (re)store radii using a named attribute
        node_mesh_to_points.inputs['Radius'].default_value = radius
        node_out = tree.nodes.new(type='NodeGroupOutput')

        tree.links.new(
            output = node_in.outputs['Geometry'],
            input  = node_mesh_to_points.inputs['Mesh']
        )
        tree.links.new(
            output = node_mesh_to_points.outputs['Points'],
            input  = node_out.inputs['Geometry']
        )
    
    mod.node_group = tree


main()


Thank you, I could indeed use set_verts_to_points. My last node in the UI would be point to vertice, then I get my vertices in python (which works), and I use your function set_verts_to_points to get back to points, which would allow me to see the color in the UI. I will test that and get back to you if that work to solve the topic. However this is really a pity that there is no way to get in python, data that is printed in the UI (see edit part of my first post).

Just for the precision: what I want basically, is to get data of my cloud point in python, and visualize this cloud point in color in the UI, given the fact that my object is a mesh initially, converted into a cloud point in GN via raycast and so on.

@GottfriedBerton still not clear... To "get" the points, just convert them to verts and read in python from evaluated copy, without the need to change the original object. To display, there's a lot of approaches - you could do it within geonodes without ever touching python.

you are right, I can indeed convert point2verts, access the vertices in python, and vert2point using your script it works.. except that it delete the initial geometry, unlink my geometry node workflow and so on (but I work on copy project of course), but on the principle it is OK. I could even don't need vert2points: just point2vertice in python on copy object to access vertices, and for display nothing to do as the object is pointcloud

@GottfriedBerton you don't need to display both objects, in the end of the day it's hard to help if you say you want to "get" point data without a broader context.

I cannot give you more context about what I do with the point cloud data (x,y,z) that is confidential, I use it for export that is all. It is true I don't need to display both object, but I suppose both will be computed so that is twice computation. But that is out of the scope of the initial question, for which you provided accepted solution
